# Suggestion to reduce show/hide code

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

This code hide date time picker from computer and show date  and time picker on mobile but in other structure.
I want to reduce code in a simple function, but I don't know how.Some sugestions? Thanks!
I wrote this code

```
 if( ismobile) {
            function showHide(){
                $(datepicker1).hide();
            $(timepicker1).hide();
            $(datepicker2).show();
            $(timepicker1).show();
            }
            $("#OF_datepicker0").hide();
            $("#OF_timepicker0").hide();
            $("#OF_datepicker00").show();
            $("#OF_timepicker00").show();

            $("#OF_datepicker1").hide();
            $("#OF_timepicker1").hide();
            $("#OF_datepicker01").show();
            $("#OF_timepicker01").show();

            $("#OF_datepicker2").hide();
            $("#OF_timepicker2").hide();
            $("#OF_datepicker02").show();
            $("#OF_timepicker02").show();

            $("#OF_datepicker3").hide();
            $("#OF_timepicker3").hide();
            $("#OF_datepicker03").show();
            $("#OF_timepicker03").show();

            $("#OF_datepicker_yacht").hide();
            $("#OF_timepicker_yacht").hide();
            $("#OF_datepicker_yacht_mob").show();
            $("#OF_timepicker_yacht_mob").show();

            $("#OF_datepicker_yacht_2").hide();
            $("#OF_timepicker_yacht_2").hide();
            $("#OF_datepicker_yacht_2_mob").show();
            $("#OF_timepicker_yacht_2_mob").show();

            $("#OF_datepicker_yacht_3").hide();
            $("#OF_timepicker_yacht_3").hide();
            $("#OF_datepicker_yacht_3_mob").show();
            $("#OF_timepicker_yacht_3_mob").show();
        }

        });
$(function() {
        $("#OF_datepicker00").datepicker();
        $("#OF_timepicker00").timepicker();

        $("#OF_datepicker01").datepicker();
        $("#OF_timepicker01").timepicker();

        $("#OF_datepicker02").datepicker();
        $("#OF_timepicker02").timepicker();

        $("#OF_datepicker03").datepicker();
        $("#OF_timepicker03").timepicker();

        $("#OF_datepicker_yacht_mob").datepicker();
        $("#OF_timepicker_yacht_mob").timepicker();

        $("#OF_datepicker_yacht_2_mob").datepicker();
        $("#OF_timepicker_yacht_2_mob").timepicker();

        $("#OF_datepicker_yacht_3_mob").datepicker();
        $("#OF_timepicker_yacht_3_mob").timepicker();

        $( "#OF_datepicker_issue" ).datepicker();
});
```

This code hide date time picker from computer and show date  and time picker on mobile but in other structure.
I want to reduce code in a simple function, but I don't know how.Some sugestions? Thanks!

Comment: use css class selectors instead of id's

Comment: And use toggle() too.

Comment: a general class for hide and a general class for show?

Comment: @TirgovatuAndreea: yes..

Comment: I can't use toogle. When I use computer my code show me a date time picker with a calendar image.On mobile, my code show me two different inputs,first with date picker and last with time picker. And now, I try to hide computer structure and show mobile structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Class selector instead of Id's

```
$(".OF_timepickerall").show();
$(".OF_timepickerall").hide();
```